# How to enlarge whole element in DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed `DIV` container size : `375px * 667px` for phone. How this `DIV` and all element inside (img,text,etc) will auto enlarge when user using a desktop browser?

[original fixed div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9jxN.jpg)
[auto enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uisXH.jpg)

Comment: Work with @media https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

The trick would be to add `height: 100%` to all elements in the dom-tree that are around the div that needs to be 100% of height.

Don't forget the body, tag, as for most browsers, your body is not bigger as the content in it.

Some browsers even need to have it set on the HTML-tag.